# How can I make my webpage background cover fixed for the full size page in css?

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS code:

```
.hero {
    position: relative;
    padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
    min-height: 900px;

    background: rgb(40, 70, 102) url('../img/hero-01.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    color: #fff;
}
```

And that makes the coverage of 100% in width, but only 900px in height. I tried to add the `height: 100%` but that didn't work. So far the webpage looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBbAU.jpg and I want to make the Video section not visible when User resize his browser to the full screen. How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also set the height to

```
height: 100vh;
```

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Example css for Hero template:

```
.hero {
  position: relative;
  padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(40, 70, 102) url('../img/hero-01.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually using this layout http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/01/27/freebie-boxify-one-page-website-template/ and I applied your changes to the CSS code, but that didn't work and the background of the first slide is still not covering the whole page, I don't know exactly why it didn't work though

Comment: I looked at the HTML and was able to get it correct, I meant 100vh. I changed the css to .hero {
  position: relative;
  padding: 60px 0 60px 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(40, 70, 102) url('../img/hero-01.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
}

Comment: Hey Thomas, that actually worked and did the trick, awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%
```

This should stretch it to 100% of both X and Y.

Comment: Hey Topher, that didn't work... I'm using this layout http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/01/27/freebie-boxify-one-page-website-template/ and I applied your changes, but still - it didn't work though

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a fiddle here? i need to check the html also. And...about the second part, you can easily do it with media queries.

Imagining the div with the video part has a class of 'video-section', you could do:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { 

    .video-section {
         display: none;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that clue, as I wrote above, I'm using this layout  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/01/27/freebie-boxify-one-page-website-template/

Comment: Well, i think it might be the parent div originating the issue. If the div that contains your image has a fixed height, you can't stretch your background so, without checking the html (too lazy to download that zip :P ) just check if that div has a height attribute.

Comment: if you keep having issues just go here https://jsfiddle.net/ and paste your html and css there. Then share your jsfiddle url so i can see and test.

Comment: Thanks for help, it was quite hard for me to make it run over there because of other dependencies in this zip file, but it is like this http://jsfiddle.net/uhs18h3s/1/ I'm not sure if it works properly now and why it doesn't in this zip itself, I'll keep looking for the solution, but thanks for your help!

Comment: As i thought, it's the video class that's messing up. If you display: none on the the .video, you will see your image occuping the space you want. So what i suggest is as the page load, you set the video class to display none, and then, when the user scrolls or resizes the window, you do 'display: block'.